# convert elements of an array from scientific notation to decimal notation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array come of whose elements are in scientific format and I want to convert them into decimal format. My numpy array looks like this:

```
[array([ 93495052.96955582,  98555123.06146193])]
[array([  1.00097681e+09,   9.98276347e+08])]
[array([  6.86812785e+09,   6.90391125e+09])]
[array([  7.75127468e+08,   8.02369833e+08])]
```

and this is formed using this line in my code:

`list1.append(np.array(regr.predict(data),dtype = np.float))`

Now I want to convert elements in `list1` from scientific format to decimal format. I looked around for some solution and found out that `print format(0.00001357, 'f')` converts numbers from scientific format to decimal format but how do I use it to convert elements of my array?

Comment: They are not in "scientific format"; internally they are floating point numbers. they only happen to be printed in said format.

Comment: @ExP so how do I convert them into normal decimal format?

Comment: Don't confuse display format with internal representation.  All computer floats are stored with an exponent.

Comment: @hpaulj so how do I make it to represent in normal format?

Comment: You can turn them into strings: `"%f" % yournumber". But then they won't be numbers anymore.

Comment: @ExP but that would be with print statement. How do I make it append the normal format number to say another list?

Comment: The "normal" format is scientific notation and I don't think you can change that.  But it makes sense, since who wouldn't rather see `1e100` than a 1 followed by 100 zeroes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off, as several people have noted, there's a very large difference between how the numbers are displayed and how they're stored.

If you want to convert them to strings, then use `'{:f}'.format(x)` (or the `%` equivalent).

However, it sounds like you're only wanting the numbers to be displayed differently when you're working interactively (or through a `print` statement).

### Changing how `numpy` arrays are printed

The way that numpy arrays are displayed interactively is controlled by [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

*Note that this does not convert the numbers to strings or change them in any way.*

As a quick example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = 1e9 * np.random.random(5)

In [3]: x
Out[3]:
array([  4.96602724e+08,   5.42486095e+08,   4.74495681e+08,
         7.37709684e+07,   9.75410927e+08])

In [4]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([496602723.824146, 542486095.316912, 474495680.688025,
       73770968.413642, 975410926.873148])
```

We've only changed how `numpy` will display the numbers. They're still floats.

We can operate on them mathematically, and they'll behave like numbers:

```
In [6]: x[0]
Out[6]: 496602723.82414573

In [7]: x[0] * 2
Out[7]: 993205447.64829147
```

### Converting to `string`s

Now let's say we had converted them to a list of strings:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = 1e9 * np.random.random(5)

In [3]: x
Out[3]:
array([  2.56619581e+08,   2.55721261e+08,   3.36984986e+08,
         2.67541556e+08,   9.01048842e+08])

In [4]: x = ['{:f}'.format(item) for item in x]

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
['256619580.697790',
 '255721261.271977',
 '336984986.430552',
 '267541556.373619',
 '901048842.193849']
```

Now they're a `list` of `string`s.  If we operate on them mathematically, they'll behave like strings, not numbers:

```
In [6]: x[0] * 2
Out[6]: '256619580.697790256619580.697790'
```

### Controlling how `numpy` arrays are saved with `savetxt`

Finally, if you're using [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt), and would like to control how the data is output to disk, consider using the `fmt` parameter instead of manually converting elements of the array to strings.

For example, if we were to do:

```
np.savetxt('temp.txt', x)
```

By default, the ascii representation of the array would use scientific notation if it is more compact:

```
8.702970453168644905e+08
9.991634082796489000e+08
5.032002956810175180e+08
2.382398232565869987e+08
1.868727085152311921e+08
```

However, we can control that using `fmt`. Note that it expects the "old-style" `%` formatting strings:

```
np.savetxt('temp2.txt', x, fmt='%f')
```

And we'll get:

```
870297045.316864
999163408.279649
503200295.681018
238239823.256587
186872708.515231
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to print them without using scientific notation, you can do `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, that only suppresses scientific notation on numbers near zero, not large numbers.  Still, it's a very useful option, regardless!

Comment: @JoeKington, current `set_printoptiions` says "scientific notation is used when
    absolute value of the smallest number is < 1e-4 or the ratio of the
    maximum absolute value to the minimum is > 1e3."